# MariaDB installation moved my Mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, database, ubuntu, mariadb

I had a working mysql database until I installed mariadb.
I was following a tutorial to install something and at some point I had to do the following command : apt-get install -y mariadb-server
I had a message in a pink screen telling me something like that my mysql/ directory has been moved to mysql-5.7
Now I think I have another database because all my users disappeared, I cannot connect to it from anywhere etc.. So I tried to rename in /var/lib/ the new mysql directory to keep it as a backup, and to rename the mysql-5.7/ directory to "mysql/"
Then I tried a "service mysql restart" but I had an error "[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB" (from systemctl status mysql.service).
I looked on internet for solutions and I find this one : " sudo -u mysql mysqld --skip-innodb --default-storage-engine=myisam"
But I have a new error in "systemctl status mysql.service" saying :

```
" /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x570)[0x52ea30]  
mysqld[130813]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f22a9354830]  
mysqld[130813]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x29)[0x523f09]  
mysqld[130813]: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains  
mysqld[130813]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.  
mysqld[130813]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x570)[0x52ea30]  
mysqld[130813]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f22a9354830]  
mysqld[130813]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x29)[0x523f09]  
mysqld[130813]: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains  
mysqld[130813]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.  

mysql[130639]:    ...fail!  
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1  
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.  
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.  
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How can I get my database back please ?
I'm running Ubuntu server 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that MariaDB can't handle your existing InnoDB tables. As far as I understand your question, you have put your old data in the right place again, but you still are using MariaDB instead of the original MySQL.

Please note that it probably is the MariaDB server which is started by `service mysql restart` because MariaDB is designed to be a drop-in replacement for MySQL.

So you already have partly solved your problem, but one step is missing. I suggest to try the following:

1) Uninstall MariaDB.

2) Reinstall MySQL.

3) Stop MySQL (it is probably already running immediately after installing it).

4) You hopefully have copied the `mysql-5.7` directory. If yes, make an additional copy of it, remove the `mysql` directory and again rename your copy of the `mysql-5.7` directory to `mysql`.

5) Restart MySQL.

If you don't have a copy of the `mysql-5.7` directory, leave out steps 3) through 5) and hope that MariaDB did not destroy your data when trying to read the InnoDB tables.

If you still want to migrate to MariaDB, you could use tools like `mysqldump` to export the data from MySQL (provided that is up again) and to re-import it into MariaDB after having installed it.